# How to multiply to (n) number of functions using for loop?

Tags: matlab

```
function box1( l, m)
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

%Define parameter 

M1=[l, m];


fin=fopen('d://box1.txt','wt');

fprintf(fin,'      XY                   %g:     %g \n',M1);
```

Comment: I have no idea what your question means, nor how it is related to your code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are **l** and **m** column vectors that you want to iterate through? In that case you could write:

```
for k=1:size(M1,1)
fprintf(fin,'      XY                   %g:     %g \n',M1(k,:);
end
fclose(fid);
```

It'd be better if you clarified that though.

Comment: function box1( l, m, s, w, a )
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

%Define parameter 
Layer=a;
M1=[l, m];
M2=[s  m];
M3=[s  w];
M4=[l  w];

fin=fopen('d://trix1.txt','wt');
fprintf(fin,'      LAYER               %g; \n',Layer);
fprintf(fin,'      XY                   %g:     %g \n',M1);
fprintf(fin,'                           %g:     %g \n',M2);
fprintf(fin,'                           %g:     %g \n',M3);
fprintf(fin,'                           %g:     %g \n',M4);

Comment: fprintf(fin,'                           %g:     %g; \n',M1);              then using funcation to execute box1(190,122,1233,1099,3);  i will get output text file like that  BOUNDARY  
      LAYER               3; 
      DATATYPE            0; 
      XY                   190:     122 
                           1233:     122 
                           1233:     1099 
                           190:     1099 
                           190:     122;                               i would like to find a way to repeat this process with oout using more variable (just parameterize